# how to reload all localized string in a WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, localization

I have a WPF window and many labels are using localized strings. For example :

```
<Window x:Class="CoHOLauncher.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.Localization">

<Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Static loc:Strings.MainWindowSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

Details of the Strings class as follow :

```
public class Strings {
        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;
        public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyNameSpace.Localization.Strings", typeof(Strings).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }

    public static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
        get {
            return resourceCulture;
        }
        set {
            resourceCulture = value;
        }
    }

        public static string MainWindowSize {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("MainWindowSize", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
}
```

If I changed  Strings.Culture in run time, how to force WPF to reload all strings ?

I store all strings in a localization satellite DLL assemblies , which are generated from localized resource files .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to change the binding source from an `x:Static` value and somehow expose the localized strings through a property that provides value change notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Static binding seems to be simply a binding to the string. In other words, it looks like, when you bind to a static variable, wpf just sets the value for the property in question and forget about the binding static element (since wpf "thinks" that the value will never change.)

What you can do is to have the xaml element a x:name set the value in the code bhind to the new value manually:

// code behind for a given event:
cancel.content = Properties.login.password;